# Appium wait until a element is clickable

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, appium

I am using appium, nodejs to write automated test case for android. I need to know how to wait until a element is clickable. I am using wd nodejs web driver library.

Answer (score 1):

```
var asserters = wd.asserters;
return driver.waitForElementById(id, asserters.isDisplayed, 10000, 100)
then(function(el){
return el.click())
```

The above function waits for an element to be displayed for 10 seconds pinging every 100ms and once **isDisplayed returns true** it clicks on the element.

Answer (score 0):

In Java it would be following:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition

import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.*    
import static org.joda.time.Duration.standardSeconds

void click(By by) {
        waitUntil(elementToBeClickable(by),standardSeconds(25))
        findElement(by).click()
    }

void waitUntil(ExpectedCondition<?> until, Duration duration) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver(), duration.getStandardSeconds())
        wait.until(until)
    }
```